# does object reference change after GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have little bit confusion about GC, when GC performs it stops all threads and collects Garbage references.

after GC , does jvm perform any compaction ?

> Compaction: means moving "in-use" memory areas to eliminate holes caused by terminated references

if yes then does jvm maintain the old references or it assigns new reference to all remaining objects?

Comment: I added Java as the language since you mention JVM. But please tag properly if you're referring to something else (e.g. Scala).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

About compaction: it depends on the algorithm used. Since all young-generation GCs are copying collectors: yes, they do campaction, they even relocate all surviving objects to a different memory-area. With old-generation collectors it depends on what collection-algorithm is used. While the standard mark-sweep-compact-collector is compacting (well, that's why the "compact" is there) the CMS-collector (concurrent mark sweep) usually does not do any compacting unless it is unavoidable and thus has to manage heap-fragmentation.

And when objects are moved (whether because of using a copy-collector or because of compaction) the existing references are updated to point to the new memory-location.

Comment: You can easily update the references for local variables, class instances and Object Array Instances. But how does the JVM handle the references pushed to operand stack?